# PouchDB to PouchDB replication via CouchDB too slow for real time applications

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-2.0

I have 2 devices (one running an electron app, the other a react-native mobile app) using PouchDB & a CouchDB 2.0 cluster to sync data between them.

My use case is for a real-time application running on the 2 devices. I have noticed that if a document is updated on one PouchDB instance, it takes anywhere around **6-11 seconds** for the newly written data to be synced with the other PouchDB instance via the CouchDB 2.0 cluster. Is this latency expected for such a setup? Is it possible to further speedup the sync times?

My trouble is that being a realtime application, that amount of latency between each update is just not feasible. Does PouchDB/CouchDB really fit my use-case?

Comment: If you're writing a realtime application, an eventual-consistency model probably isn't really what you want.

Comment: @Flimzy: I've realised that part of the latency in my case had to do with the underlying store PouchDB uses on React Native. When I changed the storage adapter to SQL Lite, the latency came down to  ~ 3 seconds. 

Regarding, eventual consistency for real-time apps, Im not sure if that's the case since Firebase is eventually consistent too - and it's designed specifically for real time applications.

Comment: I don't know anything about Firebase, but I do know that "realtime" and "eventual" are contradictory terms.

Comment: Take a look at [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/) which is built for Realtime.

Comment: PouchDB 6.2 has a couple of timing bugs that could increase latency in this scenario (see https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/6510). You could try building Pouch from master or wait until 6.3 - hopefully released in the next week - and see if that improves things